# Android gradle: what do square brackets around the version mean?

Tags: android, gradle

In Facebook Android sdk's get started guides, they define two ways to add the dependency to your project.  In the Getting Started section, the line in gradle is

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
```

but in the Quick Start guide, the line is

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

Additionally, Android Studio warns that you shouldn't use '+' in version numbers, leading to unrepeatable builds.  I have seen the '+' for other dependencies and I believe it means to get the latest version when you sync gradle, but what do the square bracket and parentheses mean in the second line?

Comment: Is this not listed in gradle syntax documentation?

Comment: See http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/settings/version-matchers.html for a full list

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It means a range.  [ means including, ) means up to.  So that would be any version starting with 4, but less than 5.  so 4.0, 4.1, 4.99999.9999 would match, 5.0 would not.  4.+ means anything 4 or greater with no upper bound.

Comment: and if I remember well a syntaxt like [4,5] means 5 is valid

Comment: So with 4.+ if they release 5.0.0, gradle would grab even the 5.0.0 version?

Comment: Yes jesse, that is what `4.+ means anything 4 or greater` means

Comment: @JesseLi Yes, it would.  It would even grab 6.0.0.  The reason for putting an upper bound is to prevent you from grabbing versions with incompatible major changes

Comment: @GabeSechan so if i have implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.7.1, 3.99.99]' does gradle always try to get the LATEST build between these two values ?

Comment: hmmm i  have implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.5, 3.99.99]'  and when i run ./gradlew app:dependencies it shows that oneSignal version is 3.6.5 installed.   So it looks like it does not get the latest version which is 3.7.1. unless im missing something.

Answer (score 2):

@GabeSechan something is strange here
athough I have:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

I get a warning in Android studio saying :

> A newer version of com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk than
>   [4,5) is available: 4.38.1

this would mean the [4,5] doesn't necessarily imports the latest version on the SDK

Answer (score 0):

For example

0.1 _ 0.3 _ 1.0 _ 1.1 _ `:[0,1) -> 0.3` _ 1.2 _ `:[1,2) -> 1.2` _ 1.3 -> `-> 1.3` _ 1.4 -> `-> 1.4`